# No visible @interface for 'PlaceMark' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:Location:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm trying to simple alter the image of a pin on the map, but I can't create the annotation due this error.

Theres my "PlaceMark.h":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface PlaceMark : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordenada;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *titulo;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)novoTitulo Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location;
-(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView;

@end
```

My "PlaceMark.m":

```
#import "PlaceMark.h"

@implementation PlaceMark
@synthesize coordenada;
@synthesize titulo;

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)novoTitulo Location:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){
        titulo=novoTitulo;
        coordenada=location;
    }
    return self;
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView=[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self         reuseIdentifier:@"ponto"];

    annotationView.enabled=true;
    annotationView.canShowCallout=true;
    annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"placa.png"];
    return annotationView;
}
@end
```

Edit:
Heres where I am instantiating the marker:

```
//heres the error
PlaceMark *ponto = [[PlaceMark alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ponto" Location:coordinate];
[_mapKit addAnnotation:ponto];
```

Already tried cleaning and Rebuild

What's wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: Is the warning in this file or in another file?  Have you tried to clean and rebuild?

Comment: You need to show the code  where you are creating the place mark and receiving the warning

Comment: there is no `@end` in your pasted implementation code. Are you missing it in your actual program?

Comment: Sorry, was missing the "@end" and the line where I instantiate

Comment: Have you included "PlaceMark.h" in the file where you instantiate the PlaceMark?

Comment: Yes, all the "includes" are correct

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into Xcode and I don't get a warning about the init method. Is the line you added where you are receiving the warning?

Comment: yes, precisely. Already tried the xcode dance also, no luck at all :(

Comment: Regardless of the error the question is about, the `PlaceMark` class, as shown, is not a valid implementation of the `MKAnnotation` protocol.  Specifically, you must implement a `coordinate` property (spelled exactly like that).  Similarly, your `titulo` property will not be used by the map view since it will be looking for a `title` property.  These problems are not causing the current error you are seeing but they will eventually generate compiler or run-time errors.